# Async/await on firebase queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

Again i'm asking for you help over firebase issues. For now i've put async/await to use the data from the snapshot outside my function but still doesent work:

```
        database.ref('adress').once('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(async function (childSnapshot) {           
                 const childKey = await childSnapshot.key;
                 const childData = await childSnapshot.val();
                         
    });             
});
```

Can i get some help?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using async function in firebase wrong way

you should using like this

```
async funcion getAdress(){
  try{
     const snapshot = await database.ref('adress').once('value');

     snapshot.foreach();
  }catch(err){
     console.error(err);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: how do i get ``` snapshot.value() ``` from this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I follow your question fully, but using the example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document as a start point, we can rework the code to use await instead of then.

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
try {
  var doc = await docRef.get()

  if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
}
```

Comment: This is for firestore and not for realtime database